# TypeError: Cannot read property 'types' of undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

I'm confused, because i have a problem with this basic tutorial --> https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-ruby/4-authentication/

I move all queries to another folder (like mutations) with this tutorial -->
https://itnext.io/graphql-with-ruby-on-rails-queries-in-multiple-files-3a7b818354a2

**I got error in GraphiQL console:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'types' of undefined
    at buildClientSchema (http://localhost:4000/assets/graphiql/rails/application-6f03c7a92432765b0fbe671bfb7a292ee6c37e6704b6e6ac95587e45676bbf72.js:34102:72)
    at http://localhost:4000/assets/graphiql/rails/application-6f03c7a92432765b0fbe671bfb7a292ee6c37e6704b6e6ac95587e45676bbf72.js:2795:55
```

**app/graphql/backend_schema.rb**

```
class BackendSchema < GraphQL::Schema
  mutation(Types::MutationType)
  query(Types::QueryType)
end
```

**app/graphql/types/user_type.rb**

```
module Types
  class UserType < Types::BaseObject
    field :id, ID, null: false
    field :name, String, null: false
    field :email, String, null: false
  end
end
```

**app/graphql/types/query_type.rb**

```
module Types
  class QueryType < Types::BaseObject
     field :get_all_users, resolver: Queries::GetAllUsers
  end
end
```

**app/graphql/queries/base_queries.rb**

```
module Queries
  class BaseQuery < GraphQL::Schema::Resolver
    # null false
  end
end
```

**app/graphql/queries/get_all_users.rb**

```
module Queries
  class GetAllUsers < Queries::BaseQuery
    type [Types::UserType], null: false

    def get_all_users
      User.all
    end
  end
end
```

**Logs from console:**

```
backend git:(master) rails s -p 4000
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.3 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.6.2-p47), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:4000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/graphiql" for ::1 at 2019-04-07 12:55:21 +0100
   (0.7ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
  ↳ /Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Processing by GraphiQL::Rails::EditorsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"graphql_path"=>"/graphql"}
  Rendering /Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/graphiql-rails-1.7.0/app/views/graphiql/rails/editors/show.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/graphiql-rails-1.7.0/app/views/graphiql/rails/editors/show.html.erb (166.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 171ms (Views: 169.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started POST "/graphql" for ::1 at 2019-04-07 12:55:22 +0100
Processing by GraphqlController#execute as */*
  Parameters: {"query"=>"\n    query IntrospectionQuery {\n      __schema {\n        queryType { name }\n        mutationType { name }\n        subscriptionType { name }\n        types {\n          ...FullType\n        }\n        directives {\n          name\n          description\n          locations\n          args {\n            ...InputValue\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n\n    fragment FullType on __Type {\n      kind\n      name\n      description\n      fields(includeDeprecated: true) {\n        name\n        description\n        args {\n          ...InputValue\n        }\n        type {\n          ...TypeRef\n        }\n        isDeprecated\n        deprecationReason\n      }\n      inputFields {\n        ...InputValue\n      }\n      interfaces {\n        ...TypeRef\n      }\n      enumValues(includeDeprecated: true) {\n        name\n        description\n        isDeprecated\n        deprecationReason\n      }\n      possibleTypes {\n        ...TypeRef\n      }\n    }\n\n    fragment InputValue on __InputValue {\n      name\n      description\n      type { ...TypeRef }\n      defaultValue\n    }\n\n    fragment TypeRef on __Type {\n      kind\n      name\n      ofType {\n        kind\n        name\n        ofType {\n          kind\n          name\n          ofType {\n            kind\n            name\n            ofType {\n              kind\n              name\n              ofType {\n                kind\n                name\n                ofType {\n                  kind\n                  name\n                  ofType {\n                    kind\n                    name\n                  }\n                }\n              }\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  ", "graphql"=>{"query"=>"\n    query IntrospectionQuery {\n      __schema {\n        queryType { name }\n        mutationType { name }\n        subscriptionType { name }\n        types {\n          ...FullType\n        }\n        directives {\n          name\n          description\n          locations\n          args {\n            ...InputValue\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n\n    fragment FullType on __Type {\n      kind\n      name\n      description\n      fields(includeDeprecated: true) {\n        name\n        description\n        args {\n          ...InputValue\n        }\n        type {\n          ...TypeRef\n        }\n        isDeprecated\n        deprecationReason\n      }\n      inputFields {\n        ...InputValue\n      }\n      interfaces {\n        ...TypeRef\n      }\n      enumValues(includeDeprecated: true) {\n        name\n        description\n        isDeprecated\n        deprecationReason\n      }\n      possibleTypes {\n        ...TypeRef\n      }\n    }\n\n    fragment InputValue on __InputValue {\n      name\n      description\n      type { ...TypeRef }\n      defaultValue\n    }\n\n    fragment TypeRef on __Type {\n      kind\n      name\n      ofType {\n        kind\n        name\n        ofType {\n          kind\n          name\n          ofType {\n            kind\n            name\n            ofType {\n              kind\n              name\n              ofType {\n                kind\n                name\n                ofType {\n                  kind\n                  name\n                  ofType {\n                    kind\n                    name\n                  }\n                }\n              }\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  "}}
uninitialized constant Queries::BaseQuery
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `block in load_missing_constant'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:8:in `without_bootsnap_cache'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `rescue in load_missing_constant'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:58:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/qwerty/projects/backend/app/graphql/queries/get_all_users.rb:2:in `<module:Queries>'
/Users/qwerty/projects/backend/app/graphql/queries/get_all_users.rb:1:in `<main>'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:48:in `block in require_or_load'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:47:in `require_or_load'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:60:in `block in load_missing_constant'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:59:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/qwerty/projects/backend/app/graphql/types/query_type.rb:3:in `<class:QueryType>'
/Users/qwerty/projects/backend/app/graphql/types/query_type.rb:2:in `<module:Types>'
/Users/qwerty/projects/backend/app/graphql/types/query_type.rb:1:in `<main>'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:48:in `block in require_or_load'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:47:in `require_or_load'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:60:in `block in load_missing_constant'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:59:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/qwerty/projects/backend/app/graphql/backend_schema.rb:3:in `<class:BackendSchema>'
/Users/qwerty/projects/backend/app/graphql/backend_schema.rb:1:in `<main>'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:48:in `block in require_or_load'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:47:in `require_or_load'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:60:in `block in load_missing_constant'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:59:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:60:in `block in load_missing_constant'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:59:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/qwerty/projects/backend/app/controllers/graphql_controller.rb:10:in `execute'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:194:in `process_action'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:256:in `process_action'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `process_action'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:134:in `process'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:52:in `dispatch'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:34:in `serve'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:52:in `block in serve'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `each'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `serve'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:840:in `call'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:559:in `call'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-cors-1.0.3/lib/rack/cors.rb:95:in `call'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:660:in `handle_request'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:474:in `process_client'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
/Users/qwerty/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Don't post links to tutorials, we won't look there. Post the code you're using which is giving you the error.

Comment: I added code parts to post.

Comment: @Smugller From the snippets you posted it seems like you are missing `Types::MutationType`. Can you comment out `mutation(Types::MutationType)` and try again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pulled code from you git repo. I have not worked with graphql but you clearly have not structured your modules and classes correctly.  Did your app ever work??  I suggest you start over with a new project and start from the very beginning if you're working from [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@IreneuszSkrobis/graphql-mutations-in-ruby-on-rails-4f93f91b1f2d)

But you might be better off with a new rails project,going step by step reading the [documentation here](https://graphql-ruby.org/).

Comment: Thank you for link to tutorial, this helps me. I delete graphql folder, generate new files with graphql:install comand and write code from scratch and it works!